# In what canonical instances has Princess Leia been shown to be decidedly Force-Sensitive, or even use any abilities?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, princess-leia

It has been said by Yoda that the Force was "Strong" within all the members of the Skywalkwer family, but I personally know of no instances in the main 3 films when she was shown to use any force powers. Considering the films added over the last 5 years, as a casual fan of the extended media, I'm uncertain what remains canon, so if she has been known to develop any Force-specific abilities.

Are there proper, creator approved instances of her using Force powers, or showing her sensitivity to be higher than that of most individuals?

Specific instances (in video, written works, or comic book panels which would be considered canon) would be appreciated.

Comment: @valorum this is connected, but not duplicated. I was asking for **specific instances in canon,** as I wasn't sure what was _still_ canon or what isn't.

Comment: The top three answers to the dupe are all from canon sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to *The Empire Strikes Back*, in *The Last Jedi* she uses the Force both to sense Kylo Ren, and then to propel herself through space back to the breached ship.

Both scenes appear in this clip

Comment: Thank you. This feels like a valid answer, at least in the last part. There were some instances in the comics, as well, shown in another question. @valorum this is connected, but not duplicated. I was asking for **specific instances in canon,** as I wasn't sure what was _still_ canon or what isn't.

Answer (score 6):

At the end of The Empire Strikes Back, Luke uses the Force to "call out" to Leia as he dangles from the bottom of Cloud City, and she "hears" him - more like feels his call. This can be construed as being sensitive to the Force.

Comment: But that could be construed as _Luke_ using the Force on her more as a "Target", not _her_ being Force-Sensitive, per say. It's much the same way a Jedi using Force Mind control could apply it to someone, and them being affected; they are using _their_ mind to reach the mind of another.

Comment: @Russhiro: It appears that what Luke did only really works with other Force sensitive people. Every example of this "communication" has only occurred with other Force users, and we've *never* seen a Force user being susceptible to the Jedi Mind Trick.